# hierarchical interfaces and implementations

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

The following code only works if you uncomment the line

```
  virtual void FuncA() { ImplA::FuncA(); }
```

in class `ImplB`, otherwise I get compiler error:

> cannot instantiate abstract class  ... FuncA(void)' : is abstract

Question is why doesn't it get the implement for `FuncA()` from the inherited `ImplA`?

```
class InterfaceA  {
public: 
  virtual void FuncA()=0;
};

class InterfaceB : public InterfaceA {
public: 
  virtual void FuncB()=0;
};

class ImplA : public InterfaceA  {
public: 
  virtual void FuncA() { printf("FuncA()\n"); }
};

class ImplB : public ImplA, public InterfaceB {
public: 
  // virtual void FuncA() { ImplA::FuncA(); }
  virtual void FuncB() { printf("FuncB()\n"); }
};

{
  ImplB *b = new ImplB();
  InterfaceA *A= b; 
  A->FuncA();
  InterfaceB *B= b;
  B->FuncB();
  B->FuncA();
}
```

Comment: Because you inherit from `InterfaceB`, which is abstract with two pure-virtual functions that you need to override.

Comment: class ImplA : public InterfaceA  {
public: 
  virtual void FuncA() { printf("FuncA()\n"); }
};

Comment: note that class ImplA is corrected as below result is the same

Comment: Your class has *two* base subobjects of type `InterfaceA`. You have provided overrides for only one of them, not for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit an instance of the "diamond" problem in multiple inheritance.
You'll need to use "virtual" inheritance (which amounts to adding the keyword virtual when inheriting)

The problem is that ImplB has two paths to the base class InterfaceA. However, your intention is that the interfaces do not provide any implementation. Thus, you need to indicate this to the compiler, so it can unify the pure virtual functions.

For a much better explanation:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

I've modified your code to add virtual when you inherit from interfaces. Now it compiles, even with the line commented. Also note, I think you are missing virtual destructors, so you'll have some other problems down the line. This code compiles, without uncommenting FuncA.

```
#include <cstdio>

class InterfaceA  {
public: 
  virtual void FuncA()=0;
};

class InterfaceB : public virtual InterfaceA {
public: 
  virtual void FuncB()=0;
};

class ImplA : public virtual InterfaceA  {
public: 
  virtual void FuncA() { printf("FuncA()\n"); }
};

class ImplB : public ImplA, public virtual InterfaceB {
public: 
  // virtual void FuncA() { ImplA::FuncA(); }
  virtual void FuncB() { printf("FuncB()\n"); }
};

int main()
{
  ImplB *b = new ImplB();
  InterfaceA *A= b; 
  A->FuncA();
  InterfaceB *B= b;
  B->FuncB();
  B->FuncA();
}
```

Comment: Many many many thanks ! This has been bothering me for some time now, you totally nailed. I'm in your debt.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance isn't "mixins"

You can inherit from multiple classes that have methods with the same name but that doesn't make them the same.

The thing that inherits from a virtual class must implement the pure virtual functions of its parents.

If the method names weren't scoped, you could end up with combinations of parent classes that were mutually exclusive to inherit from because the implementations of the method with the shared name wouldn't be compatible.

I am a bit surprised that putting `using ImplA::FuncA;` in ImplB doesn't solve it, though:  https://gcc.godbolt.org/